# What do the different kinds of arrows between classes and interfaces in this Hibernate diagram mean?

Tags: hibernate, uml

I am trying to understand [the following diagram](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/images/architecture/JPA_Hibernate.svg) from http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html for relationships between Hibernate's classes.

[image]
I am not quire sure what the different kinds of arrows mean, and I guess they are not following UML diagram specifications. Could someone explain what the different kinds of arrow mean? Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess those were made with some Eclipse tool :-/

Answer (score 4):

The circled `I`s and `C` (likely for interface and class) are no UML standard. However, you can adorn stereotyped classes with icons at your wish. Though I doubt that the standard classes here need a stereotype to mark them as "standard class".

I'd guess that the

- dotted arrows with filled triangles should be Realizations (since they point to interfaces). These would need an unfilled triangle in UML to be correct.
- The same goes for the solid lines with filled triangle which are likely generalizations. UML needs unfilled triangles here.

Anything else (which isn't much) seems fine.

- Dependency with dashed line and open triangle
- Directed associations with composite shown by filled diamond.

Comment: Thanks, Is **Directed Association with Composite** a standard UML notation?

Comment: @Gholamali-Irani Yes, it is. See also https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html

Comment: @Thomas Kilian: The term "Directed Association" is not a UML standard term. In fact, UML only defines navigability arrows, but no concept of "directionality" as needed for uni- and bi-directional associations.

Comment: @GerdWagner Yes, you are right. I was using it more in a colloquial sense to say that they Indians were using the right arrows here.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand it, it is not an UML diagram.

- The arrow between SessionFactory and SessionFactoryImpl coudld be a generalization, but in UML the arrow is empty not filled as in your diagram
- The arrow between Transaction and TransactionImpl seems to be a realization relation, but in UML there is no composition but a dash line with an empty arrow
- The arrow between TransactionImpl and EntityTransaction may be a dependency but in UML this is an open arrow.

Comment: @Gholamali-Irani I'd say it's an UML diagram with syntactical errors ;-) Like you wouldn't say "this sentence not is English" is not English but wrong English.